# No transparency after converting opaque to transparent shader in Unity, need help identifying my mistake

Tags: unity-game-engine, hlsl

I have a working opaque shader that i'm currently trying to convert to a transparent shader. I followed tutorials online but for some reason the shader still shows the object as opaque. I feel like i'm missing something very obvious but can't figure out what it is.

```
Shader "Custom/WaterSphere"
{
   Properties
   {
      _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
      _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
      _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
      _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
      _PlaneNormal("PlaneNormal",Vector) = (0,1,0,0)
      _PlanePosition("PlanePosition",Vector) = (0,0,0,1)
      _Transparency("Transparency", float) = 0.1
   } 
   SubShader
   {
       Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
       LOD 200

       CGPROGRAM

       #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

       #pragma target 3.0

       sampler2D _MainTex;

       struct Input
       {
           float2 uv_MainTex;
           float3 worldPos;
       };

       half _Glossiness;
       half _Metallic;
       fixed4 _Color;
       fixed3 _PlaneNormal;
       fixed3 _PlanePosition;
       float _Transparency;

       bool checkVisability(fixed3 worldPos)
       {
           float dotProd1 = dot(worldPos - _PlanePosition, _PlaneNormal);
           return dotProd1 > 0  ;
       }

       UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)

       UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

       void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
       {
           if (checkVisability(IN.worldPos))discard;
           fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
           o.Albedo = c.rgb;
           o.Metallic = _Metallic;
           o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
           o.Alpha = _Transparency; //Has no effect
       }
       ENDCG
   }
   FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Blending is off by default, you need add it manually.

```
SubShader
{
    Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
    LOD 200

    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by replacing

```
#pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows
```

with

```
#pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows alpha:fade
```